# absolute vs relative urls and how browsers interpret hrefs to send http requests

Tags: html, http, browser, absolute-path

I want to know how browsers send http requests based on absolute link which starts with a forward slash say /images/myimage.jpeg. Now if i have server replication and say http://foo.com request can go to any of the servers say server 1, server 2 and server 3 and I have images only on server 1. Now if i send a request for a page mypage.html and the request goes to server 2 and mypage.html has a link with  href="/images/myimage.jpeg". I want to know that clicking on that link would search for myimage.jpeg in the images folder on the local hard drive of server 2 from where the page mypage.html is fetched or there would be http request that could go on any of ther server something like http://foo.com/images/myimage.jpeg.

Answer (score 0):

you are directly requesting foo.com server to look into images/ directory for the file mymage.jpg. If the foo.com resolves to server1 and server1 has the images/myimage.jpg then it will be downloaded to your browser. Otherwise it wont. But instead if you have the image in a < img href=server1/images/myimage.jpg> tag which will always resolve to server1 and get the images displayed on the browser.